# Unknown unit/mL

Tags: psychiatry, psychopharmacology, schizophrenia, pharmacopsychiatry

In the book [Kaplan and Sadock's synopsis of psychiatry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078177327X):

> Clozapine. Clozapine (Clozaril) levels are trough levels determined in
>   the morning before administration of the morning dose of medication. A
>   therapeutic range for clozapine has not been established; however, a
>   level of 100 mg/mL is widely considered to be the minimum therapeutic
>   threshold. At least 350 mg/mL of clozapine is considered to be
>   necessary to achieve therapeutic response in patients with refractory
>   schizophrenia. The likelihood of seizures and other side effects
>   increases with clozapine levels greater than 1,200 mg/mL or doses
>   greater than 600 mg per day or both. Clozapine is a common cause of a
>   leukopenia in psychiatry. When moderate to severe leucopenia develops,
>   clozapine treatment must be interrupted, but patients may be retreated
>   with clozapine in the future.

What is "mL" here?

<sub>Sadock, B. J., & Sadock, V. A. (2011). [Kaplan and Sadock's synopsis of psychiatry: Behavioral sciences/clinical psychiatry.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078177327X) Lippincott Williams & Wilkins.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

(edit, actually found the book text on Google books and paid a bit more attention to the context; the book is Kaplan & Sadock's Concise Textbook of Clinical Psychiatry by Sadock, Sadock, and Ruiz, and you can find the specific passage by [searching for the quoted text](https://books.google.com/books?id=-PbZDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT95&lpg=PT95&dq="levels+are+trough+levels+determined+in+the+morning+before+administration+of+the+morning+dose+of+medication"))

This book is talking about plasma concentrations of drugs. Based on the actual plasma concentrations for clozapine  with typical doses, this looks like just an error or typo: mL means milliliters, but these numbers would be more appropriate if they were in *nanograms* rather than milligrams, milligrams is several orders of magnitude too high and well beyond the solubility of clozapine in water.

Comment: Indeed, [from a review paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22327098), _"The lowest effective clozapine levels ranged from 250 to 550 µg/L, while the recommended upper limit to prevent toxicity varied from 600 to 2000 µg/L [0.002 mg/mL]."_. That is a big error. :O

Comment: The [book I found](https://goo.gl/TU4Lu6) states "A therapeutic range for clozapine has not been established; however, a level of 100 nanograms per milliliter (ng/mL) is widely considered to be a minimum therapeutic threshold." This is not the same book the OP listed though, but based on it (Kaplan & Sadock's Concise Textbook of Clinical Psychiatry). Maybe they corrected it here, or it was an erroneous copy/paste/typo of the OP.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Might be correct in an earlier or later version but the one on Google Books I link to shows the same error as OP.

Comment: Well, that only further confirms your answer! :)